# Apply changes from .Xdefaults to running rxvt terminals

Tags: rxvt, x-resources

Is there a way to apply (for example the font(size)) changes to `.Xdefaults` to all running terminals in a session?

I can apply it to new terminals via loading xrdb -load .Xdefaults, but this doesn't apply to all running terminals.

If it matters I am using urxvt (in daemon mode) as terminal and xmonad as window manager on ubuntu 15.10.

Just for the font sizes I had the idea that one could use the fontsize perl-extension to inject a fontsize change to each open terminal, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't believe so because each terminal is a separate instance and totally independent of every other. However, I am not particularly familiar with urxvt. I just know that the original hardware terminals were never intended for anything like that, so I doubt highly that that functionality exists.

Answer (score 1):

A quick read of `urxvt(1)` and then from the synopsis of the mentioned `urxvt(7)` reveals that `rxvt-unicode` terminals support escape sequences that can alter e.g. the font:

```
SYNOPSIS
          # set a new font set
          printf '\33]50;%s\007' 9x15,xft:Kochi" Mincho"
```

These would have to be printed into each open terminal, and some translation would likely be required to convert the `.Xdefaults` format into something suitable for such printing.

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the configuration is a feature that not all programs support. X resources in particular are usually read when a program starts up; there's no protocol to notify an application that it should use new resources¹. Rxvt tends towards being small, so it's no surprise that it doesn't support reloading its configuration after startup.

*Some* settings can be changed dynamically. In particular, [the font can be changed via control sequences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261057). You can emit these control sequences from anywhere, just redirect the output to the right terminal device:

```
printf '\33]50;%s\007' … >/dev/pts/42
```

I can't think of a way to list the terminal devices that rxvt is providing. You can easily list the devices where you have processes running, this may be good enough.

```
for pts in $(ps x -o tty= | sort -u); do
  case "$pts" in pts/*) printf … >"/dev/$pts";; esac
done
```

¹  <sub>Actually, there is one — editres — but who's heard of editres? Nobody, that's who.</sub>