# How do I inform Firefox about a change in the X server resource database?

Tags: x11, firefox, x-resources, xrdb

When docking/undocking my laptop, I change `Xft.dpi` in the X server resource database using `xrdb`. After that happened, I would like to inform as many applications as possible that they should re-read and apply the changed settings.

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261389/347377):

> Reloading the configuration is a feature that not all programs support. X resources in particular are usually read when a program starts up; there's no protocol to notify an application that it should use new resources¹. Rxvt tends towards being small, so it's no surprise that it doesn't support reloading its configuration after startup.

Firefox is a bit bigger than Rxvt therefore my question:

*Q*: How do I inform Firefox about a change in the X server resource database?

Related:

- [Apply changes from .Xdefaults to running rxvt terminals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261044/347377)